# Reachable set of finitely many known one-parameter groups acting on an Hermitian space

Tags: group-theory, manifolds, lie-algebras, group-actions

I have an orthonormal basis $\{ b_{\{1, 2\}}, b_{\{1, 3\}}, b_{\{2, 3\}}\}$ of the Hermitian space $\mathbb{C}^{3}$, with Hermitian product denoted by $(\cdot, \cdot)$, and the induced norm by $|\cdot|$.  The basis vectors are indexed by the size 2 subsets of $\{1, 2, 3\}$.  Since these indices are sets, $b_{\{p, q\}} = b_{\{q, p\}}$.

We will use the tensor product notation to define linear operators on $\mathbb{C}^{3}$, as follows: if $u, v$ are vectors in $\mathbb{C}^{3}$, then the operator $u \otimes v$ is defined to send $x \in \mathbb{C}^{3}$ to $(v, x) u$.

Suppose we are given the one-parameter groups
$$
g^{t}_{(1 \; 2)} = {1 \over 2}
\left(
\left(b_{\{3, 1\}} + b_{\{3, 2\}}\right)^{\otimes 2} +
e^{i 2 \pi t} \left(b_{\{3, 1\}} - b_{\{3, 2\}}\right)^{\otimes 2}
\right) + b_{\{1, 2\}}^{\otimes 2},
$$
$$
g^{t}_{(1 \; 3)} = {1 \over 2}
\left(
\left(b_{\{2, 1\}} + b_{\{2, 3\}}\right)^{\otimes 2} +
e^{i 2 \pi t} 
\left(b_{\{2, 1\}} - b_{\{2, 3\}}\right)^{\otimes 2}
\right) + b_{\{1, 3\}}^{\otimes 2},
$$
$$
g^{t}_{(2 \; 3)} = {1 \over 2}
\left(
\left(b_{\{1, 2\}} + b_{\{1, 3\}}\right)^{\otimes 2} +
e^{i 2 \pi t} 
\left(b_{\{1, 2\}} - b_{\{1, 3\}}\right)^{\otimes 2}
\right) + b_{\{2, 3\}}^{\otimes 2},
$$
acting on $\mathbb{C}^{3}$.  (These groups are indexed by transpositions of pairs of elements in $\{1, 2, 3\}$.)

It can be shown by direct computation in the orthonormal basis
$$
c_1 = b_{\{1, 2\}}, \; c_2 = {1 \over \sqrt{2}}\left(b_{\{3, 1\}} + b_{\{3, 2\}}\right), \; c_3 = {1 \over \sqrt{2}}\left(b_{\{3, 1\}} - b_{\{3, 2\}}\right),
$$
the group $g^{t}_{(1 \; 2)}$ fixes $c_{1}, c_{2}$  and preserves the equality $|\left(x, c_{3}\right)| = $const.  Namely,
$$
g^{t}_{(1 \; 2)} c_3 = 
e^{i 2 \pi t} c_3.
$$
It follows that
$$
\left|\left(g^{t}_{(1 \; 2)} x, c_{3} \right) \right| = 
\left|\left(x, c_{3} \right) \right|.
$$

Analogous statements and computations hold for the other two groups, implying that all three groups are subgroups of the unitary group $\mbox{U}\left(3, \mathbb{C}\right)$.

The following setting, and some of the notation, is that of the [Nagano-Sussmann Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbit_(control_theory)).
Define the orbit of a point $x \in \mathbb{C}^{3}$ as the set
$$
{\cal O}_{x} = \{ g^{t_{k}}_{\alpha_{k}} g^{t_{k-1}}_{\alpha_{k-1}} \ldots g^{t_{1}}_{\alpha_{1}} x \; : \; t_{j} \in \mathbb{R}, \alpha_{j} \in \{(1 \; 2), (1 \; 3), (2 \; 3)\}, k \in \mathbb{N}, j = 1, \ldots, k \}.
$$
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be the Lie algebra generated by the tangent vectors
$$
\left.{d \over dt}\right|_{t=0} g^{t}_{\alpha},
$$
and let $\mathfrak{g}_{x}$ be the evaluation of this Lie algebra at $x$.  Let $y$ be another point in ${\cal O}_{x}$.  My question is: Does there necessarily exist an element in $\mathfrak{g}$ with the corresponding one-parameter group $g_{y}^{t}$,
$$
y = g_{y}^{t} \, x \mbox{ for some } t>0?
$$

It would seem that ${\cal O}_{x}$ is the 3-D sphere, but the evaluation of the Lie algebra generated by the $g^{t}$ is not of the same dimension at every $x \in \mathbb{C}^3$.  Thoughts?  Criticisms?

Comment: Yes, of course: You are effectively asking if the subgroup generated by the given 1-parameter subgroups $G_1,...,G_m$ of $T^D$ has the Lie algebra equal to the span of the Lie algebras of $G_1,...,G_m$. Try to prove it yourself by considering first 1-parameter subgroups of ${\mathbb R}^D$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  The one-parameter groups are not subgroups of $T^{D}$ viewed as a group.  As I understand it, $T^{D}$ is an abelian group.  My one-parameter groups *act* on $T^{D}$ as a topological space.  I don't think they commute with each other.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I see: Then you should explain how the operators that you wrote are acting on the torus, which is very much unclear (even when $D=1$).

Comment: @MoisheKohan  You are right, I didn't make it clear.  I have the specific form of the operators, so I'll edit the question accordingly.  Thank you so much for your feedback, as always.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, I put a complete description of the one-parameter groups for $D=3$, the case I decided to restrict the question to.

Comment: I do not even see why what your $g^t$'s are subgroups of $GL(3,C)$ (or why they preserve the torus). If they indeed are, they will generate a subgroup of the torus $T^3\subset SU(3)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan  I reexamined the construct, and you are right: each group preserves a different object, diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{1}$.  I included the proof above.  I think it also shows that each one-parameter group is a subgroup of $\mbox{GL}(3, \mathbb{C})$.